# Processing Raster Calculator not working in Processing Graphical Modeler in QGIS

Tags: qgis

Why is Processing Raster Calculator not working in Processing Graphical Modeler in QGIS?

I am currently doing a MCDA in Qgis and I need to get a final output from the model using raster calculator but unfortunately, an error arises at the final stage of doing the overlay in raster calculator

Comment: I've also had the same problem. Sometimes [gdal raster calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html#gdalrastercalculator) can work